# Migrating legacy asp .net 4.x from server 2008 r2 to AWS EC2 server 2019, has anyone else seen a serious performance drop?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server

I have about 20 legacy web applications that are in the process of being rewritten in .Net Core. We have had to migrate them in the meantime to AWS on an EC2 with server 2019. On our physical server using 2008 r2, these 20 applications run fine. However, on the EC2 after I have about 10 of the applications running things start to have serious lag. I have tried to work with the app pool settings. I have the app pools recycling every 120 minutes and have also set another recycle if the memory exceeds a certain threshold. I am only using 1 worker process for application. I basically have matched the settings as close as possible to those from the server 2008 r2 iis. I have also chosen an EC2 that as closely as possible matches the resources of the physical server. My real question is, is there something significant that changed from iis 7.x that might have been defaulted in the settings that has to be manually configured on the newer version? This is ridiculous, is it possibly just because this is an EC2?

I have tried working with the app pool settings to no avail. My next thought would be to increase the number of available worker processes per each app pool. Each application has it's own app pool. The memory being consumed never goes above 18 - 20% in the task manager, and the cpu might hit 10%.

Comment: Factors impacting ASP.NET 4.x web apps are far more than the ones IIS offers, so step one is not to guess what might be the settings but analyze the slow performance directly. Learn tools like performance profilers and use them to get started.

Comment: @LexLi things run perfectly fine until I have more than 10 applications in IIS on the 2019 EC2. I have run performance tests on the individual applications and am not seeing anything that specifically stands out. They all run perfectly fine on the physical server 2008 R2 without an issue and quite snappy at that?

Comment: Like I said, there are more factors you need to put into consideration. Windows Server did change significantly in the past decade, so as physical to virtual. So, you shouldn’t expect web apps to work exactly the same way. Performance testing is different from profiling, so you might see if anyone within your organization has the experience on that. You will have to hire someone if needed.

Comment: Well, do keep in mind there is a MASSIVE difference between cloud computing and hosting compared to that of a hosted server. So, just like a welding contractor has a diesel generator on the back of the truck? The reason is simple: You can't draw that much power from the Grid without effecting other users - so there are boatloads of CPU and memory "governors" that limit CPU and memory use. Same reason why fire trucks have their OWN water hydrants -you can't let ONE household draw that much water without effecting other users. So, cloud computing = MUCH more limited computing power then a server

Comment: In other words, you going to have to allocate more ram, and more CPU computing to those hosted sites. You don't mention how much your giving now, but as noted these so called "utility" computing systems have much less CPU, and less ram then your typical hosted server.

Comment: Ensure that the EC2 instance type and size you've chosen align with the resource requirements of your applications. You may need to consider instances with higher CPU, memory, or network performance, depending on the characteristics of your applications.